# awk: fatal: cannot open file `' for reading (No such file or directory)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to read x and y coordinates from a node in a grid. The coordinates of all the nodes are in the file mesh_coords.xyz. I want the one referring to line 1055, which refers to a place called Jalisco.

```
nodes_file='../output/ascii/mesh_coords.xyz'

jalisco=`awk '{if (NR==1055) print $0}' ${nodes_file}`

x=`awk '{print $1}' ${jalisco}`
y=`awk '{print $2}' ${jalisco}`
```

Returns: "awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `4250.000000' for reading (No such file or directory)" twice (I assume once for x and once for y).

However:

```
nodes_file='../output/ascii/mesh_coords.xyz'

awk '{if (NR==1055) print $0}' ${nodes_file}
```

prints the correct x and y coordinates.
I need to use the variables x and y later so they need to be set properly.

I'm relatively new to Linux so apologies if this is a simple awk/shell syntax problem.

Comment: use `$()` instead of backticks.

Comment: It looks like `$jalisco` contains the result of executing the previous awk command, which is a number. You're then trying to use it as a filename, which doesn't exist.

Comment: `awk '{if (NR==1055) print $0}'` can be more succinctly written `awk NR==1055`

Comment: In the example which works, you are looking at nodes_file, not jalisco.

Comment: Chances are your approach is wrong as you are calling awk step by step from shell when the right approach is almost certainly to just do the whole job in a single awk command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the `$jalisco` variable is holding x-y co-ordinates separated by space in a string. Obviously `$jalisco` is not a file hence your last 2 awk commands are giving errors.

You can use this:

```
x=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "${jalisco}")
y=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "${jalisco}")
```

Or better yet, get both values from your first awk itself using **process substitution**:

```
read x y < <(awk 'NR==1055' "$nodes_file")
```

Also note that your `awk` command can be shortened to just:

```
awk 'NR==1055' "$nodes_file"
```

The default action is to print the line, so this is what awk will do when the condition `NR==1055` is true.